# Login/Logout is required in each scenario for performance testing?

Tags: jmeter-5.0

I have 10 scenarios. Each scenario needs to be run with different-different threads. Login/logout is required for functional testing but in performance testing . Is it required ?.If yes. Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, Yes login / logout is also the part of application functionality and ideally it also requires a performance test.

You can use an if controller in jmeter for your test plan to test the login/logout of your application.

https://octoperf.com/blog/2019/03/28/jmeter-if-controller/